# why the program can't stop after downloaded all the emails?

Tags: php, email

There are 2465 emails in my gmail,why the program can't stop  after download all the emails?  All code1 and code2 are run in command line mode.
code1:

```
<?php
$mailbox = array(
    'mailbox'  => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'yyyy'
);

$stream = imap_open($mailbox['mailbox'], $mailbox['username'], $mailbox['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($stream,"ALL");
$nums=imap_num_msg($stream);
echo $nums;
foreach($emails as $email_id) {

            $mime = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, "");
            file_put_contents("/tmp/" . "email_{$email_id}.eml", $mime);
        }

imap_close($stream);
echo "over";
?>
```

For code1 :
1.can download all the emails.
2.output 2465 on the console
3.no `over` output on the console.
4.the program can't stop ,it seems to run forever.

code2:

```
<?php
$mailbox = array(
    'mailbox'  => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'yyyy'
);

$stream = imap_open($mailbox['mailbox'], $mailbox['username'], $mailbox['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($stream,"ALL");
$nums=imap_num_msg($stream);
echo $nums;
foreach($emails as $email_id) {
            echo  $email_id.PHP_EOL;
            $mime = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, "");
            file_put_contents("/tmp/" . "email_{$email_id}.eml", $mime);
        }

imap_close($stream);
echo "over";
?>
```

For code2:
1.can download all the emails.
2.output 2465 on the console .
3.`over` output on the console.
4.the program stop after download all the emails.

There is one line `echo  $email_id.PHP_EOL;`  in code2 more than code1,other codes are same.
All code1 and code2 are run in command line mode.
Who can explain it ?

[image]

Comment: You say it hangs up with doing nothing? As long as CPU isn't at 100%, it probably hangs in some syscall, … try a `strace` then and look what the last syscall(s) are.

Comment: Try settings timeout for fetching email with **imap_timeout** - your echo can accidentially make this timeout for second script.

Comment: Can you still reproduce the error ? If so what php version are you using and what shell are you on while executing the scripts ?

Comment: did you try to print the `$emails` array or see the count of it to ensure that it doesn't have any blank entries in it?

Comment: How are you connecting to the machine actually running the script?  If it's remote, it could be that the inactivity over stdio (the terminal connection), whilst it fetches and downloads the message on the remote computer, exceeds your connection timeout.  Given how long it takes to get to 'over' in code2, can you connect a separate window to the machine running code1 and see if the process is actually, still running, after the same amount of time.  Similarly check the script time limit, in php_cli

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print imap_last_error();
```

Before and after `imap_close` to know more about what causes your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check `imap_fetchbody()` function, this function allows you to set download limit and with this you can stop after all mail downloads. Check below code, I made some changes into your code that will stop download process after all mails are download. Please check once.

```
<?php
$mailbox = array(
    'mailbox'  => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'yyyy'
);

$stream = imap_open($mailbox['mailbox'], $mailbox['username'], $mailbox['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());

//Check all mails...
$imap_obj = imap_check($stream);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX...
$nums=imap_num_msg($stream);
$emails = imap_fetch_overview($stream,"1:{$imap_obj->Nmsgs}",0);

echo $nums;
//Loop until mail data...
foreach($emails as $objEmail_data) {
    $mime = imap_fetchbody($stream, $objEmail_data->msgno, "");
    file_put_contents("/tmp/" . "email_{$objEmail_data->msgno}.eml", $mime);
}

imap_close($stream);
echo "over";
?>
```

And see the results!

I replaced `imap_search()` with `imap_fetch_overview()` and made some relevant changes.

Let me know if any further help required.

Comment: I have tested every kinds of status.

Comment: all the code ,my code1 code2 and  
AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd'code can run with putty to connect my vps ,and get all the same result  both on command line mode and on browser mode. local os  is windows, server os is debian7.

Comment: local os is debian7, server os is debian7, my code1 run on browser mode ,get the wanted result.when my code1 run on command line mode ,can't stop after download all the emails .

Comment: So, i draw the conclusion that it is a problem of  hibernation on debian7 ,the programs run so long time ,nothing output cause the debian console sleep until all the emails downloaded ,it can't wake .

Comment: The method to disable hibernation on my  debian7 remain some bugs.

Comment: I have no more idea about debian7, I am providing you suggestion after goggling, if your debian7 os is having some issue then you need to check at [checking the package for errors](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/checkit.en.html) OR [Keeping your Debian system up-to-date](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-uptodate.en.html).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've seen strange behaviours back on the time with memory leaks... But PHP is quite stable now. Try gc_collect_cycles... Or surround your echo with ob_ functions... Sorry :p I'll check this post sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$mailbox = array(
    'mailbox'  => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'yyyy'
);

$stream = imap_open($mailbox['mailbox'], $mailbox['username'], $mailbox['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($stream,"ALL");
$nums=imap_num_msg($stream);
//echo $nums; // removed this
foreach($emails as $email_id) {

            $mime = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, "");
            file_put_contents("/tmp/" . "email_{$email_id}.eml", $mime);
        }
unset($emails); // added this
imap_close($stream);
die ("over"); // changed this
?>
```

I have reset the emails variables.

Comment: The whole point of the question is that it never leaves the `foreach` loop.